# Nav bar isn't working properly?

Tags: nav

So I'm making a website for a school assessment, and I was wondering why my Nav bar links are always slightly below the actual nav bar itself. If anyone could help that'd be great :).

```
    ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1px;
  top: -10px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: 0px;
  padding: 10px 89.5px;
  background-color: #6C2DC7;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;

}
ul li:hover {
  background:  #8467D7;
  }

a:link {color:#FFFFFF;} /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#FFFFFF;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FFFFFF;} /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* selected link */
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

[This is what it looks like on my website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQczT.png)

Comment: send me a link to website if its not local and i will take a look? or do a jsfiddle

Comment: http://ditcs.neocities.org/ Cheers.

Comment: fixed it @mitchell check my answer

Comment: ahh, thank you man :) much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change this it will work:

line 75 of your style.css

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

really you should make this just for your nav bar and not for every ul so you could change it to the below: up to you though both ways work :)

```
 #navigation ul {
        text-align: center;
        top: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: -5px;
    }
```